# Google Chrome 21 is not supporting --disable-web-security command line switch

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Since the latest release of Google Chrome browser version 21.* and Selenium Chrome Driver version 22.* , the special command line switch “--disable-web-security”  which we have been using to test our iframes with different domain is no longer supported (deprecated).Is there any workaround for the same to automate our frame which is in different domain in Chrome browser?

Our existing functional Automation framework completely depends on this switch (--disable-web-security).Response would be appreciated.

Comment: If a particular answer is helpful in solving your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark next to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome - disable web security - no longer working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918393/chrome-disable-web-security-no-longer-working)

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a workaround, the flag still works, what's new is the warning.

I just performed a test using jQuery to send an AJAX request to another domain and it worked using the command-line flag, and it didn't when not using it.

It would be nice to have a way to disable the "yellow infobar", though.

(I'm running Chrome 21.0.1180.60).

Answer (score 0):

You might also have to kill all running instances of the Chrome.exe running in the background before using the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What turned out to be the issue is even after you close chrome... there is a chrome.exe process running. Kill it using taskmanager and the flag will work even in version 28