# --disable-web-security not working anymore in Chrome 30

Tags: google-chrome

I updated Google Chrome to **Version 30.0.1599.69 m**. Now the `"--disable-web-security"` flag is not working. How do I to disable the websecuritiy in Google chrome **Version 30.0.1599.69 m**

Comment: `--disable-web-security` works for "Chrome version 31.0.1650.48". If you see "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer", then it is working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome - disable web security - no longer working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918393/chrome-disable-web-security-no-longer-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend disable web security command with --user-data-dir. This worked for me, more details are on >https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690

Command I use in windows :

```
"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk" --disable-web-security  --user-data-dir
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is with the chrome instance running in the task bar.

> Please check whether any other instance of the Chrome is running in
>   the task bar. Even a single instance will not let chrome reflect the
>   command.

Kill all and then try running this command again.