# getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, deprecation-warning

I am getting this error on my website which requests Geolocation data from the user:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See [goo.gl/rStTGz](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.

I mean its basically just a notice, and the google link just says its being deprecated.

I have no plans on moving my website to SSL... so is there an alternative for someone like me?

Comment: Lets hope their won't just shut the feature down without replacement in the future release...

Comment: They are likely to shut the feature down without replacement in a future release. That's exactly why they are deprecating it now. Quote *we expect to gradually migrate these features to secure-only*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a likely answer in /jstillwell's posts here:
https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps/issues/15
basically this feature will not be supported (in Chrome only?) in the future, but only for HTTP sites. HTTPS will still be ok, and there are no plans to create an equivalent replacement for HTTP use.

Answer (score 47):

Because switching to HTTPS can be painful or impossible depending on your architecture,
I found a workaround solution: you can use the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro). Although it has usage limits, it does the job. You will need an browser API key, so don't forget to limit it's usage to your page hostname.

I use it as a fallback method to the `getCurrentPosition()` method if it fails. It allows me to make it work until I switch to HTTPS.

Here's the JSFiddles:

- [HTTP](http://jsfiddle.net/gogs/jwt9f1o3/): `getCurrentPosition()` will fail and fall back to the API
- [HTTPS](https://jsfiddle.net/gogs/jwt9f1o3/): `getCurrentPosition()` will succeed

Comment: Hi, can you post an example please? Thanks

Comment: I am will still getting the warning message, that's ok?

Comment: Yes because the fiddle only use the API when the browser geolocation fails (when you get the warning).

Comment: Thx @gogson for the tips ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that the example uses JQuery.

Comment: Also, the Google Maps Geolocation API does not mention GPS but rather network access points (wifi, cellular) or IP geo-info as fallback. So it seems HTTPS is essential now.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the precision. Soon we will all need to switch to HTTPS due to Chrome strict policy. The sooner, the better.

Answer (score 25):

It's only for test, you can do it in google chrome:
navigate to: [chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure](http://chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure)
then you'll see:
[image]
Type address you want to  allow, then **enable** and **relaunch** your browser.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Works as a charm!

Comment: Just note you also have to change the drop-down on the right to the **Enabled** state. It's a bit confusing in that it automatically prompts you to save and relaunch Chrome when you change the field, but it doesn't automatically enable it. Took me several attempts before I realized.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Google Chrome has deprecated the feature in version 50. If you tried to use it in chrome the error is:

`getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.`

So, you have to add SSL certificate. Well, that's the only way.

And it's quite easy now using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org). Here's [guide](https://timkadlec.com/2015/12/taking-lets-encrypt-for-a-spin/)

And for testing purpose you could try this:

> 1.localhost is treated as a secure origin over HTTP, so if you're able to run your server from localhost, you should be able to test the feature on that server.
>
> 2.You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" flag (replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that you also need to include the --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.

I think Firefox also restricted user from accessing GeoLocation API requests from `http`. Here's the webkit changelog: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/200686

Comment: I'm geeting info: "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure. Stability and security will suffer". Chrome version: 50.0.2661.102. Also gelocation still not working

Comment: Kill all instances and try again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918393/the-disable-web-security-command-is-seems-no-longer-working

Comment: When testing out your app in the chrome browser, just change the apps url (generally 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000) to localhost:3000 .. You will need to make sure your media policy supports it, but you will not get a security error.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the https://ipinfo.io API for this (it's my service). It's free for up to 1,000 req/day (with or without SSL support). It gives you coordinates, name and more. Here's an example:

```
curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "172.56.39.47",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Oakland",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.7350,-122.2088",
  "org": "AS21928 T-Mobile USA, Inc.",
  "postal": "94621"
}
```

Here's an example which constructs a coords object with the API response that matches what you get from `getCurrentPosition()`:

```
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/geo', function(response) { 
    var loc = response.loc.split(',');
    var coords = {
        latitude: loc[0],
        longitude: loc[1]
    };
});
```

And here's a detailed example that shows how you can use it as a fallback for `getCurrentPosition()`:

```
function do_something(coords) {
    // Do something with the coords here
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
    do_something(position.coords);
    },
    function(failure) {
        $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/geo', function(response) { 
        var loc = response.loc.split(',');
        var coords = {
            latitude: loc[0],
            longitude: loc[1]
        };
        do_something(coords);
        });  
    };
});
```

See http://ipinfo.io/developers/replacing-navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition for more details.

Comment: What antivirus do you have installed on your machine, or network?

Answer (score 8):

You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com" flag (replacing "example.com" with the origin you actually want to test), which will treat that origin as secure for this session. Note that you also need to include the --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir to create a fresh testing profile for the flag to work.

For example
if use Windows, Click Start and run.

```
chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://localhost:8100"  --user-data-dir=C:\testprofile
```

Comment: And how does one get users to do this?

Comment: On Mac: `/usr/bin/open -n "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args "http://localhost:8100" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://localhost:8100" --user-data-dir=/tmp/testprofile`

Answer (score 2):

For dev only, you can authorize specific local domains to use this features:

https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/enabling-the-microphone-camera-in-chrome-for-local-unsecure-origins-9c90c3149339

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP the error occurs.

Set permission for **localhost** in bellow label(Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)).

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the geoLocation API is better but for people whom can't use an SSL, you can still use some sort of services such as [geopluginService](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php).

as specified in the documentation you simply send a request with the ip to the service url `http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx` the output is a serialized array so you must need to unserialize it before using it.

Remember this service is not very accurate as the geoLocation is, but it is still an easy and fast solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use `FireFox` or any other browser instead of `Chrome` if you want to test it on your development environment, for production there is no way except using `https`.

For development environment just open `http://localhost:8100/` on FireFox and alas no such error.

Comment: Firefox 64: "A Geolocation request can only be fulfilled in a secure context."

Comment: Safari 12: "[blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://0.0.0.0:8060."

Comment: Opera 57: "[Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS."

Answer (score -3):

Give some time to install an SSL cert `getCurrentPosition()` and `watchPosition()` no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.