# Full screen and geolocation button does not work in my web map

Tags: html, github, backend, web-frontend, folium

I have created a web mapping about a national park with HTML and after a repository and
obtain a host in Github in this link: https://cristianalvar.github.io/, where everything works well, however when I post that web map using the before Github URL in the next webpage: http://parqueslosrios.cl/sitio/pn-alerce-costero/, the two buttons in the left-up part does not work, i.e. full-screen and geolocation as you can try and I highlight in the next imagine:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what can be the problem and how can I solve it please?? when you press the geolocation button you received in a frame this message:

"Geolocation error: Only secure origins are allowed (see: HTTPS:...."

thanks!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858628/unable-to-use-navigator-geolocation-due-to-only-secure-origins-are-allowed

Comment: thanks @AadityasivaSabarinathan, but all the post there said it's about https security, but in Github I clicked the option: Enforce HTTPS, so it should have this domain, what else can be? also the full-screen botton does not work... thanks!

Comment: @AadityasivaSabarinathan, we solved the problem with the localitation botton adding a SSL certificate, however still we have the problem with full-screen botton, have anybody some ideas how can I solve it?? thanks!!