# Leaflet - locate() did stop working on cellphones

Tags: heroku, leaflet

locate() did stop working on smart devices, it works fine on desktop, as expected. **The weird thing is that it worked fine on cellphones until a few days.**
I have web hosted on heroku and pointed to my own domain.
The message error is: _*"Geolocation error: Only secure origins are allowed"*

I tryed the Geolocation API, it works randomly on cellphones, but I don't get the of secure origin message error.

Thanks in advance for any tip. Best!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106849/getcurrentposition-and-watchposition-are-deprecated-on-insecure-origins

Comment: It seems the https it is the way to go