# Free alternatives to getCurrentPosition() for websites without SSL?

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, location

Firstly, I am aware that this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106849/getcurrentposition-and-watchposition-are-deprecated-on-insecure-origins) exists. I am in need of a free (or very cheap) solution so I'm asking this question again.

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Chrome has disallowed the usage of getCurrentPosition() for websites without SSL.

Google Maps API could solve this but its [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/usage-limits) is way too low. (We are managing a news portal with more than 400,000 page views per day).

Does anyone know any free (or very cheap) alternative to getCurrentPosition()?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the https://ipinfo.io API for this (it's my service). It's free for up to 1,000 req/day (with or without SSL support). It gives you coordinates, name and more. Here's an example:

```
curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "172.56.39.47",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Oakland",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.7350,-122.2088",
  "org": "AS21928 T-Mobile USA, Inc.",
  "postal": "94621"
}
```

Here's an example which constructs a coords object with the API response that matches what you get from `getCurrentPosition()`:

```
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/geo', function(response) { 
    var loc = response.loc.split(',');
    var coords = {
        latitude: loc[0],
        longitude: loc[1]
    };
});
```

And here's a detailed example that shows how you can use it as a fallback for `getCurrentPosition()`:

```
function do_something(coords) {
    // Do something with the coords here
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
    do_something(position.coords);
    },
    function(failure) {
        $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/geo', function(response) { 
        var loc = response.loc.split(',');
        var coords = {
            latitude: loc[0],
            longitude: loc[1]
        };
        do_something(coords);
        });  
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks but this does not answer my question. thanks still