# Got an error when trying to get the geolocation in safari on iOS 10

Tags: geolocation, ios10

[blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://www.hnsjb.cn.

Should I change my website to the https protocol?

Comment: Faced same issue, tried https, but it didn't help.

Comment: I will try https later today. See what can I get

Answer (score 22, accepted):

iOS 10 and also desktop Safari 10 seem to require https connection now. Safari also seems to be more strict than what Chrome did earlier. No mixed content warnings are allowed, Chrome allows e.g. map tiles to load over normal http.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find any guideline specific to Safari, but this issue has been discussed by other web browsers as well.

In particular, the announcement about Google Chrome blocking geolocation over an insecure connection, published on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only) in April 2016, under the last paragraph “I really need to use Geolocation. What should I do?”, advises:

> If you would like to use the HTML5 Geolocation API, or if your site already uses the Geolocation API, please migrate the pages making Geolocation API calls to HTTPS, ensuring that they’re used in a secure context.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37276372/6527366) provides a workaround using [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).

Comment: Unfortunately the new Safari browser (10) does not allow geolocation even from HTTPS when the page has mixed content (images from HTTP). This broke my web app on safari

Comment: I tried HTTPS just now and it works. As Jamgold said ,only when all contents are from https