# getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Deprecated getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on HTTP calls.its working locally but when i am deploying my application on aws server then i am getting above error. so how can I fix it without switching to https? or if i want to switch my application on https then what all will be the steps for that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It works, but only if you have a HTTPS website.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106849/getcurrentposition-and-watchposition-are-deprecated-on-insecure-origins

Comment: A deprecation warning is not typically an error. Does it not work?

Comment: no its not working