# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition/watchPosition is not working in android 6.0

Tags: javascript, android, html, geolocation

Here is my javascript code :

```
function getLocation() { 
    //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoor, errorCoor, {maximumAge:60000, timeout:30000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
    var mobile =jQuery.browser.mobile;
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if(mobile){
        watchLocation(function(coords) {
        var latlon = coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude;
         //some stuff
      }, function() {
        alert("error");
      });
    } else {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
}

function watchLocation(successCallback, errorCallback) { 
    successCallback = successCallback || function(){};
    errorCallback = errorCallback || function(){}; 
    // Try HTML5-spec geolocation.
    var geolocation = navigator.geolocation; 
    if (geolocation) {
        // We have a real geolocation service. 
        try {
          function handleSuccess(position) {
            alert("position:"+position.coords); 
            successCallback(position.coords);
          }  
          geolocation.watchPosition(handleSuccess, errorCallback, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 5000 // 5 sec.
          }); 
        } catch (err) { 
            errorCallback();
        }
    } else {  
        errorCallback();
    }
}
```

I have tried both `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition`.

It's reaching `errorCalback()` method when control comes to `geolocation.watchPosition` line.

I am testing in `Motorola G 2nd Gen` with `Android 6` and `Google chrome browser` and `opera mini`.

**Update 1:** When I put alert in error call back function I got `error:1; message:Only Secure origins are allowed(see:`[link](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)).

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, function(e)
    {  alert(e); //alerts error:1; message:Only Secure origins are allowed(see:  )
       console.error(e);
    })
```

**Update 2:** With the help from [g4s8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723695/g4s8) I am able to findout that the error is because of insecure URL. i.e only accessing with `http` instead of `https`.But then also I bypassed that in browser by clicking advanced button.But it will prompt for **`Do you want to allow location`**, which I don't want..is there any way to access location without prompting it?

Comment: Did you try to add 2nd param (error callback) to `getCurrentPosition` method? `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, function(e) {console.error(e);})`

Comment: yes...you can see the 2nd line which is commented...`errorCoor` is that callback function...

Comment: Can you print error to console and add error message to this question? It may contain useful information. e.g. `PositionError {code: 1, message: "User denied Geolocation"}`

Comment: @g4s8 i got `PostitionError`..when i put alert(e)..but how to find console in mobile browser?

Comment: You can cannect to android device from google chrome. See this link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Comment: In this case you can show error code and message in alert: `function (err) {alert("error: " + err.code + "; message: " + err.message);}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your page should be served over https to access geolocation API.

See [Geolocation API Removed from Unsecured Origins](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

> Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the user's location using the HTML5 Geolocation API from pages delivered by non-secure connections
>
> ...
>
> It is an important issue as it will directly impact any site that requires use of the geolocation API and is not served over https

To fix this serve your page over https or on `localhost`.

---

> Thank you...Is there any way to bypass it??

You can try to use some geolocation services, e.g.
[geoip2](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-services), [Geolocation request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#overview)

---

> how to use them? can you show an example?? from those two can i access user location without knowing them?

GeoIP2 detect you location by ip address. You can obtain country (`geoip2.country()`) and city (`geoip2.city`) with js lib:

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/ you can find full documentation.

Google maps geolocation is google service, so you need to [get api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/get-api-key) first. Then you can send POST request with json parameters to `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY` and get the response:

```
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 51.0,
    "lng": -0.1
  },
  "accuracy": 1200.4
}
```

where location is the user’s estimated latitude and longitude, in degrees,
and accuracy is the accuracy of the estimated location, in meters.

Full json parameters defenition you can find in "Request body" section here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#overview

Also you can find useful those answers: [getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106849/getcurrentposition-and-watchposition-are-deprecated-on-insecure-origins)

---

> using IP it provides only country and city..??

Yes, only this.

> will it provide physical location like how getCurrent Position provides??

No, you can't get physical location, because it can be accessed only via gelocation API, that was restricted in insecure context.

Also you have **one more option**. You can host only one page (that access geolocation API) on https server, and redirect from this page to your http site with user location in get parameters.

```
/* https page */
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (result) {
    window.location.href = "http://your.site.com/http-page?lat=" + result.latitude + "&long=" + result.longitude;
});
```

Comment: Thank you...Is there any way to bypass it??

Comment: how to use them? can you show an example?? from those two can i access user location without knowing them?

Comment: g4s8 using IP it provides only country and city..?? will it provide physical location like how getCurrent Position provides??