# JavaScript : Get user location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to get user location . But there is an error like this

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

This is the part of code that tries to get location

```
  function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

Is there a way to get getlocation using HTTP server (not HTTPS).

Comment: You can use services like http://ipinfo.io/developers/full-ip-details to find location from ip address, if that is what you like.

Comment: that will not give me precise information , will that?

Comment: On the contrary, it can be really erratic at times. Why do you hate HTTPS so much?

Comment: I am doing some tests on my computer :) and my computer is the server . And I dont know how to make that test website HTTPS)

Comment: https://www.browsersync.io/ gives you an HTTPS server to play with. There will probably be a warning on Chrome though

Comment: but can I render ejs files with that module? not html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132004/discussion-between-user3578286-and-boy-with-silver-wings).

Answer (score 2):

No, specifically in Chrome.

In order to get user location in the browser u must be under HTTPS.

If you are using Cordova and creating mobile app you can access the location without https, using native features.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/#cordova-plugin-geolocation

Also you may use free HTTPS service : https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example to get user location with JavaScript.

[**Live CodePen Demo**](https://codepen.io/joshstovall/pen/ewMGQK)

**HTML**

```
<div id="nudge">
  <p>YO CAN I GET YOUR LOCATION?</p>
  <button id="theButton">yes</button>
</div>

<span id="startLat"></span>
<span id="startLon"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var button = document.getElementById('theButton');
var nudge = document.getElementById("nudge");
var latitude = document.getElementById('startLat');
var longitude = document.getElementById('startLon');

button.onclick = function() {
  var startPos;
  var showNudgeBanner = function() { nudge.style.display = "block"; };
  var hideNudgeBanner = function() { nudge.style.display = "none"; };
  var nudgeTimeoutId = setTimeout(showNudgeBanner, 5000);

  var geoSuccess = function(position) {
    hideNudgeBanner(); clearTimeout(nudgeTimeoutId); startPos = position;
    latitude.innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
    longitude.innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
  };

  var geoFail = function(error) {
    switch (error.code) { case error.TIMEOUT: showNudgeBanner(); break; } };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFail);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has removed the Geolocation API usage from insecure origins from Chrome 50. 
You can read about it [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only).
There are basically three workarounds depending on what you are trying to achieve.

1. **Use IP Location Services**

These use the users IP address to find their location. Sites like [IPInfo](http://%20ipinfo.io/developers/full-ip-details) for this purpose. However these can be really erratic at times and may not provide the accurate location if you need one.

2. **Use [Google Maps Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) API**

This obviously comes with usage limits. You can limit it to being a fallback option with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37276372/4374566

3. **Use [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/)**

If your only issue is getting it to work on the localhost(because your site would have https) then using the Browsersync test server is a boon. 
After installing Browsersync with

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

You can start a secure server from command line with

```
browser-sync start --https
```

This will throw a warning page first time on Chrome (*They are really looking out for us*), but you can skip that.

However amidst all the workarounds it is really possible that other Browsers are looking to implement the same. [Here](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/04/30/deprecating-non-secure-http/comment-page-1/) is Firefox.
So the best solution might be to get an HTTPS certificate for the site with services like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).