# How to access geolocation in mobile web browser

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm used html5 geolocation 
I made from the documentation

```
getLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition, this.showError);
   } else {
       alert("geolocation not support");
   }
},
```

code working if i'm using chrome (toogle device toolbar)
but in mobile browsers chrome(android) safari(ios) showing error

> User did not share location

how to fix it ?

On phones geolocation enabled

> UPD: Most likely this is due to the fact that there is no ssl certificate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest browser updates to get geolocation, you need to use the

> SSL certificates

for safari browser
[answer from this question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37276372/4543464)

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers have the same APIs built in. So you will have to figure out what browser a client is using and write different code depending on what APIs are included. You can figure out what browser they are using by checking the user agent.

Comment: You are used html5 geolocation?Everywhere the same`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`