# Ionic2: Geolocation working on Safari, but not on Chrome - Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome, ionic2

I'm developing an Ionic2 web application that will run on the browser on two mobile devices Android and iOS. My application uses the Cordova geolocation plugin. When testing, geolocation works on computer browsers, on iOS mobile browsers (iPhone, Ipad..etc). Unfortunately, it isn't working on Android on Google Chrome.

Comment: The problem is that the new browsers require SSL for geolocation to work, you can also use the Google API. [answer from this question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37276372/4543464)