# HTML, Javascript and CSS not working (linking- need assistance)

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i'm trying to put https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/Ozbzqq/ onto repl.it (This project) --> https://repl.it/@John_Nicole/EcstaticDarkorchidDegrees
<-- click run

My code also works on Brackets (the codepen code) so it must be repl?

Now there a a couple of unnoticeable issues (not):

1. The JavaScript isn't loading in, just like the CSS. I tried `<script src="index.js"></script>`
2. The CSS isn't loading in, is it not connected right? I have only ever used Codepen so i have never worked with linking before (between CSS, HTML, JS)
3. 2 was typed before 1. ^
4. The HTML is not flexiable (boostrap) so when, if it works it wont flex.

Here are all my links & stuff, i really need some clarification on how to do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your local weather</title>


<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>


</head>
```

Any help is accepted, i'm sorry if thy acting like such a 'noob' but we all learn somewhere. I have never used this area before, and its my weaker area of HTML.

I never included a JavaScript tag because i didn't think something is wrong there, as it works on the codepen. Do API's not working on repl.it ?

```
    // Line 10
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          lon = position.coords.longitude;
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var api =
            "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" +
            lat +
            "&lon=" +
            lon;
          $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
```

Comment: You have jquery in twice, no need for `<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` here

Comment: add full qualified/relative path of js file and remove multiple reference of jquery

Comment: Okay i removed the double Jquery. Now whats this 'relative path' to js? I tried ```<script src="index.js"></script>``` I also updated my code (removed what you told me too). Keep in mind my old code also worked on Brackets.

Comment: so... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You did big mistake when you edit `html` page inside **replt.it**.

1. You need add `script tag` in `body` or `head`  for add `external` `js` file
   but you add both inside `head` and `body` `tag`. You need to remove
   `script` `tag` from `head` `tag`.
2. **repl.it** Don't recognize `href="css/style.css"`. This your big mistake. You need to check where you `write` the `CSS` code. [check
   the image](http://prntscr.com/igqnmq). Your custom `CSS` file name is `index.css` not
   `style.css`. **repl.it** haven't any `absolute file path`. like
   `css/style.css`. If you add new `css` file called `custom.css` it
   should be `href="custom.css"`.

I created new snippet for you in [repl.it](http://rahulmoral.repl.co/LegitimateDraftyRar/) check it and compare it.

According to [user9319687](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9319687/user9319687) comments. Now `issue` is `JavaScript` isn't running. No, It's wrong `JavaScript` is running properly. **repl.it** unable to run this `script`. This **Google** `GEO` `Location` services need `https://` server. [Open this link](http://rahulmoral.repl.co/LegitimateDraftyRar/) then go to console.

> [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.

Need more information about the `HTTPS` and `HTTP` issue check it [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106849/getcurrentposition-and-watchposition-are-deprecated-on-insecure-origins) and [Github](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps/issues/15)

- Solution 1: Run this project in `HTTPS server` then it will work.
- Solution 2: Run this project in `localhost server` then it will work.

If you think how [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) is running this `script` because of [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) running in `https server`.

Comment: ```You need to remove script tag from head tag.``` I did that, and added to the body (```<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>```) and nothing? I also tried using ```href``` too.

Comment: Check the link https://repl.it/@RahulMoral/LegitimateDraftyRar and http://rahulmoral.repl.co/LegitimateDraftyRar/

Comment: The JavaScript isn't loading in. That is a placeholder, not the actual weather. Here is my repl right now --> https://repl.it/@John_Nicole/EcstaticDarkorchidDegrees