# How to allow geopositing in Intellij Idea and apply chrome flags "unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure"

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm, geopositioning

Is there a way to pass development browser flags in IntelliJ Idea (or WebStorm) ? (as it is in *chrome "unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure"* [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58664780/9277453))

[image: IntelliJ IDEA react-app config]

If I try to get user geolocation with

`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`

I get this error and it doesn't allow me to debug my webapp directly from IntelliJ

[image: geolocation unsafe origin error]

But I successfully debug it in Chrome in dev tools

Seems to be in IntelliJ there is no place to add dev-flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Web Browsers`

Go there, find your browser (or just create your own custom entry) and add command line arguments or select custom data directory (that points to existing user profile) there.

[image]

To ensure that those flags/params will be applied you would need to have that **browser closed** when **launching your Run/Debug** Configuration.

In your case you should add `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://192.168.1.101:3000"` or any other flag separated with a space.

Comment: thanks for your help, do i need to add just ```'unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure'``` or it must be something like ```'unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=true'```?

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov See the question you have quoted, just a different answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37590176/783119

Comment: could you check my edit and reject/apply them? I hope they will be helpful for others

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov Are you sure about `http://localhost:8100` part? Looking at your first screenshot I would expect a different host:port details there.

Comment: yea, you're right, in my config (on my pc) I've changed it and used the flag successfully, but here it was kind of typo. I've corrected that according to my example